# Explicit formula for heat equation in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm trying to find an explicit formula for heat equation in the interval $(0,L)$, with $L>0$. I have the next boundary-initial value problem.
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_t-u_{xx}=0, &\text{in } (0,L)\times (0,\infty), \\
u(0,t)=u(L,0)=0 & \\
u(x,0)=f
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
with $f$ a smooth function such that $f(0)=f(L)=0$.

I have the next suggestion: Extend a function $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)$ and $f(L-x)$ are odd.

**My question is**: how do I extend this function?

After that, I think that I just have to apply the fundamental solution for Heat equation (Evans PDE book).

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is
$$
         u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin(n\pi x/L)e^{-n^2\pi^2 t/L^2}
$$
where the constants $a_n$ are chosen so that
$$
      f(x)=u(x,0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin(n\pi x/L).
$$
Therefore,
$$
             \int_0^{L}f(x)\sin(n\pi x/L)dx =a_n\int_0^L\sin^2(n\pi x/L)dx \\
         \implies a_n = \frac{\int_{0}^{L}f(x)\sin(n\pi x/L)dx}{\int_0^L\sin^2(n\pi x/L)dx}
$$